# Chances are it'd be spurned on the grounds of implausibility

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

> If you were to make up a story as astonishing as Anne Boleyn's, chances are it'd be spurned on the grounds of implausibility.

1) I want to know whether "it" is referring to "chances" or what?

2) And I want to know the meaning of the clause.

Comment: *Chances are* is an idiom meaning "It is probable": this is followed by a 'content clause' optionally introduced by *that*, so "It is probable that it would be spurned ..." *It* obviously refers to something spoken of previously; we have no way of knowing what unless you post the context.

Comment: You mean that the pronoun "it" is referring to "a story" ?

Comment: Yes: it refers to the story you hypothetically made up.